# How to pass a file and list_of_strings to search as a command line arguments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

previously I am opening a file to search for a list of strings using a function

```
def search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, list_of_strings):
    line_number = 0
    parsing = False
    list_of_results = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
            for string_to_search in list_of_strings:
                if string_to_search in line:
                    print("================================================================================================")
                    print('Line:' , line_number, '', line.strip())
                    #print('[ERROR]feature = ',Exception, ", action = ", 'signalhandler' , ", no = ", 'signalno')
                    #print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                    next(read_obj)
                    for line1 in read_obj:
                        if line1.startswith(">>>>>>backtrace_"):
                            parsing = True
                        if line1.strip().endswith("<<<<<<backtrace_end"):
                            parsing = False
                        if parsing == True:
                            print(line1.strip())
                        else:
                            print("<<<<<<backtrace_end")
                            break

search_multiple_strings_in_file('CrashDump.log', ['[ERROR]feature=Exception, action=signalhandler, no='])
```

Output for the above code:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line: 980  [ERROR]feature=Exception, action=signalhandler, no=14[SIGALRM] Thread[TKEL_Timer]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>>>>>backtrace_start
0x75fc7edc : /usr/lib/libchal.so.1(+0x29edc) [0x75fc7edc]
0x770c08e8 : linux-vdso.so.1(+0x8e8) [0x770c08e8]
0x76c12854 : /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x6854) [0x76c12854]
<<<<<<backtrace_end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line: 1114  [ERROR]feature=Exception, action=signalhandler, no=1[SIGHUP] Thread[TASK_PLAYER]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>>>>>backtrace_start
0x75fc7edc : /usr/lib/libchal.so.1(+0x29edc) [0x75fc7edc]
0x770c08e8 : linux-vdso.so.1(+0x8e8) [0x770c08e8]
0x76c2031a : /lib/libpthread.so.0(raise+0x3a) [0x76c2031a]
<<<<<<backtrace_end
```

But, now I need to pass the file name and `list_of_strings` as a command line argument. I tried like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        print("Pass a file to parse as an argument")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        search_multiple_strings_in_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

but it's not getting the correct output (the correct output is the one I have written above).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? *its not getting the desired output* is not a clear problem statement. Are you getting errors? Wrong output?

Comment: Your edit doesn't really change anything... We understand that you don't get the desired output (which is above). What output ***you do*** get? Also as the question is about command line arguments, please show us how you run your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['[ERROR]feature=Exception, action=signalhandler, no=']` is an array containing a string. `sys.argv[2]` is a string.

You need

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        print("Pass a file to parse as an argument")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        search_multiple_strings_in_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:])
```

Now the first command line argument is the filename and the following arguments are passed in a list as second argument to the function, e.g.

```
python3 prog.py "CrashDump.log" "[ERROR]feature=Exception, action=signalhandler, no="
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer for my question, I have done this way:

```
    
import sys


def search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, list_of_strings):
    #local variabes declaration
    line_number = 0
    parsing = False
    list_of_results = []

    #opening the file as read_obj in read mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
            for string_to_search in list_of_strings: #searching the string in the file
                if string_to_search in line: #if string is present in the particular line it will enter the if condition
                    print("================================================================================================")
                    print(line.strip())
                    next(read_obj)
                    for line1 in read_obj:       #In this for loop, printing the logs present between the two strings ">>>>>>backtrace_" and "<<<<<<backtrace_end"
                        if line1.startswith(">>>>>>backtrace_"):
                            parsing = True
                        if line1.strip().endswith("<<<<<<backtrace_end"):
                            parsing = False
                        if parsing == True:
                            print(line1.strip())
                        else:
                            print("<<<<<<backtrace_end\n")
                            break

        print("================================================================================================")


file_to_parse = sys.argv[1] #Assigning the argument to a variable
search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_to_parse, ['[ERROR]feature=Exception, action=signalhandler, no='])
```

command to execute:(passing only file)

```
    
python3 prog.py "CrashDump.log"
```

And for the list_of_strings as an argument we can do like this:

```
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        print("Pass a file to parse as an argument")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        search_multiple_strings_in_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:])
```

For running the script:

```
    
python3 prog.py "CrashDump.log" "[ERROR]feature=Exception, action=signalhandler, no="
```